# Kruskal's Algorithm In C And What It Does

Tags: c, kruskals-algorithm

I have this code my professor gave me about finding MST's using Kruskal's Algorithm. However, I do not understand exactly what the need for

```
int parent[10]
```

is and what is happening when we are using the functions

```
find()
```

and

```
uni()
```

Below is the full code that he gave us.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int parent[10];

int find(int i)
{
    while(parent[i])
    {
        i=parent[i];
    }
    return i;
}

int uni(int i,int j)
{
    if(i!=j)
    {
        parent[j]=i;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int cost[10][10],u,v,i,j,min,mincost=0,n,ne=1,a,b;
    printf("Enter no. of vertices: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("Enter Adjacency Matrix:\n");
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&cost[i][j]);
        }
    }

    while(ne<n)
    {
        min=999;
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
            {
                if(cost[i][j]<min)
                {
                    min=cost[i][j];
                    a=u=i;
                    b=v=j;
                }
            }
        }

        u=find(u);
        v=find(v);
        if(uni(u,v))
        {
            printf("\n%d edge(%d -> %d)=%d",ne++,a,b,min);
            mincost += min;
        }
        cost[a][b]=cost[b][a]=999;
    }

    printf("\nMin. cost of spanning tree=%d",mincost);

    return 0;
}
```

I am just looking for an explination of the three things that I stated above. I understand how the algorithm works except for the three things that I stated.

Thank you

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("Enter Adjacency Matrix:\n");
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&cost[i][j]);
        }
    }`  if `n` is greater than 9, then undefined behavior will result due to accessing beyond the end of the matrix   `cost[][]`  Sadly, there is no check for such a invalid value (just as there is no check of the returned value from `scanf()` to assure the operation was successful

Comment: in C, array indexes start at 0, not 1, so the first row of the `cost[][]` array and the first column of each row will never be set to any known value

Comment: regarding: `for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&cost[i][j]);
        }`  if the scanned value is >9 or less than 0 Then the result (in function: `find()`) is undefined behavior.

Comment: regarding: `cost[a][b]=cost[b][a]=999;`  in the `find()` function this will result in undefined behavior due to accessing beyond the end of the `cost[][]` array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code supports a maximum of 10 vertices.

- `parent` is keeping track of the parent of the node.
- `find` is used for finding the vertex in a set (say A) which does not have any parent.
  So if u is in set A and v is in set B, the two sets are being unioned by `uni` function.

This code works but it is not how you code.

About the algorithm itself:

Kruskal is a greedy algorithm for finding the minimum spanning tree with the least (or maximum cost). The algorithm is as follows:

- Sort all the weights in ascending or descending order.
- Find the edge with a minimum (or maximum cost).
- If the edge is `uv` check if `u` and `v` belong to the same set. If yes do nothing repeat from step 2.
- If no union the sets in which `u` and `v` are present i.e if u is in set A and v in set B union A and B as C and discard A and B. Now `u` and `v` belong to C. Repeat from step 2.

Here is a better code :
https://github.com/26prajval98/DSA/blob/master/graph%20algorithms/kruskal/main.c